# Extract a substring based on next column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns. `A` and `B`. In column `B`, I have values like `XXDDSSSSS`, the important thing here that `X` can appear `1` time or `n` number of times but it will always be followed by a number. i.e., `VD32lasjdflsak` or `VDS34dfsadfllo`. I want to populate Column `A` from Column `B` so that it has all letters from beginning till when the first letter appears i.e., in first example column `A` should have `VD` and in next example column `A` should have `VDS`

Answer (score 1):

Not as cool as `Aggregate`, but does the trick!

```
=LEFT(B1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},B1&"0123456789"))-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=LEFT(A2, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$9)/(CODE(MID(A2, ROW($1:$9), 1))<65), 1)-1)
```

The position is hard-coded as 1 through 9. This could be adjusted with INDIRECT to 1 through the length of the string if that is insufficient.

[image]

Comment: could you explain this? also what do you mean by indirect?